# Javascript replace a character with a space

Tags: javascript

I need to get the name of the page from a url. I did this way:

```
var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
// -> 'state.aspx' 

var statelookup = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
// -> 'state'
```

Now for e.g, my statelookup has a value like New-York or North-Carolina, how do I replace hyphen with a space in between?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`string.replace(/-/g,' ');`

Will replace any occurences of `-` with  in the string `string`.

Answer (score 4):

You would use String's `replace` method:

```
statelookup = statelookup.replace(/-/g, ' ');
```

[API Reference here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

```
statelookup = statelookup.replace('-', ' ')
```