# How to change single char from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which contains the following string

```
placeholder = "<strong>Total Damage:</strong> $70,000.00"
```

Now, I am trying to replace Dollor sign($) with pound sign(£).  Any idea how this can be done?

**[Edit]**

I don't know javascript, still trying to learn. now the solution seems so simple, I feel embarrassed now. Sorry for bothering everyone with such silly question :(

Comment: Googling `javascript replace character` should give you everything you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript replace a character with a space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985722/javascript-replace-a-character-with-a-space)

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2116614/29995)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
placeholder = placeholder.replace("$","£");
```

Simples!

Answer (score 3):

Really?

[JavaScript Replace](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php)

var myNewString = myOldString.replace("something", "new thing");

Answer (score 2):

```
placeholder = "<strong>Total Damage:</strong> $70,000.00".replace("$","£");
```